# Printing problem when webscraping with BeautifulSoup and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm kinda new into programming, but I've been trying to web scrape some websites just to practice, however, I always encounter myself with this problem. The code is so simple as it is shown below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import csv

url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/soccer/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

post_box = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': '_1poyrkZ7g36PawDueRza-J'})

for info in post_box:
    title = info.h3.get_text()
    print(title)

filename = 'reddit_soccer.csv'

f = open(filename, 'w')

headers = 'Title\n'


f.write(headers + '\n')

f.write(title + '\n')

f.close()
```

Now, here's the problem, this code gives me an output with the titles of each post in the url's first page. But when I write `print (title)` in my IDE it returns only one post, which happens to be the last one on the page. I've been trying to figure it out why this happen for like hours, but I couldn't get to a reason. 
Isn't it supposed to print all the titles? If not... How am i supposed to write this output with all the titles into a csv file?

Thanks in advance and sorry for eventual grammar errors.

Comment: What does `len(post_box)` return?

Comment: Heya, thanks for replying. It returns '13'

Comment: Could you post the actual output of your program as seen in the command line?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. It successfully prints the first titles.

Comment: @DYZ 
It does print the first titles, but when writing it to a csv file it won't export all titles shown in output. I think that this is happening because if i write 'title' all alone it will print just the last title.
Any thoughts why this is happening?

Thanks for answering

Comment: @YacineMahdid, Thanks for answering. The code works fine, but I can't seem to write it to a csv, as it will only export the last result of the titles printed in the command.

Comment: Well that's another issue then, could you write your code that you use to write to a csv?

Comment: Sure! I didn't manage to put in here, so I edited the original code in the question, thanks!!

Comment: You did not show your full code. Your question is in a totally different place: in the CSV writer. You must write the title _in_ the loop, not _after_ the loop. Each iteration of the loop overwrites the vlue of the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not show your full code. Your problem is in a totally different place: in the writer. You must write the title in the loop, not after the loop. Each iteration of the loop overwrites the value of the variable.

```
filename = 'reddit_soccer.csv'
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    headers = 'Title'
    f.write(headers + '\n')
    for info in post_box:
        title = info.h3.get_text()
        f.write(title + '\n')
```